# How to find all jpgs with possible hyphens without http?

Tags: php, regex

If you have this string:

```
$str = ';s:27:"2018/08/hello-there-003.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:23:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"hello-there-003-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"hello-there-003-300x200.jpg"';
```

Is it possible to get all jpgs from it and replace it to something else?

The matches should be:

```
hello-there-003-150x150.jpg
hello-there-003-300x200.jpg
```

And replaced to:

```
replacement.jpg
replacement.jpg
```

So resulting string is:

```
 $str = ';s:27:"2018/08/replacement.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:23:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"replacement.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"hello-there-003-300x200.jpg"';
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/ Simpler regular expressions are better. Maybe parse the string into tokens, massage key parts, and reassemble the tokens.

Comment: **(?<=\")[a-z\-\d]+.jpg** https://regex101.com/r/2xgKUz/1, i can add as answer if it works for  you. For replacing it, you will do it coding, that's on you.

Comment: looks like a broken sterilised array

Comment: Lucas, that works perfect! but how would you then replace the results within the string? Oh you said that's on me, what is the approach though, is it a foreach loop and str_replace?

Comment: This looks very much like a serialized string. If you access it as a string rather than deserializing and access each data point correctly you are likely to corrupt the data for future processing. e.g. `27` before `2018/08/hello-there-003.jpg` is because there are 27 characters there.

Comment: This question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you might use:

`"\K[\w-]+(\.jpg)(?=")`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4ygiE/1)

Replace with

`replacement$1`

**Explanation**

- `"` Match "
- `\K` forget what was matched
- `[\w-]+` Match 1+ times a word character or a hyphen
- `(\.jpg)` Match .jpg in a capturing group
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right side is a double quote

For example:

```
$re = '/"\K[\w-]+(\.jpg)(?=")/';
$str = ';s:27:"2018/08/hello-there-003.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:23:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"hello-there-003-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"hello-there-003-300x200.jpg"
';
$subst = 'replacement$1';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SR7UZ)